# I have a problem on running my flutter Apps on IOS simulator

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello guys now I'm facing a problem as my laptop is Macbook Pro 7.1 and the maximum upgrade that I can get for it is High Sierra 10.13.6 and I have downloaded Xcode 10.1 and the flutter doctor says for me that flutter doesn't work on Xcode 10.1 and I can run any flutter App on IOS, please tell me Any help because I just bought this Laptop as second hand laptop and I can't afford getting new one.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Flutter SDK ususally requires the current latest version of Xcode for it's iOS app builds.

> Install the latest stable version of Xcode (using web download or the Mac App Store).

Source link for this: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#install-xcode

There's no specific requirement guide for it to know which xcode version is supported for any specific flutter version. So, it'll be very difficult for you to depend on any old apple mac devices for flutter development.

If you are planning for doing flutter iOS occassionally, then my suggestion would be to look for online mac alternatives like mac in cloud, etc.

If you have bought the mac device for the sepcific purpose of iOS development, it is not going work out in long term, possibly starting from now only.

The main reason being that Xcode depends on which latest mac OS you have & mac OS depends on which latest mac device you have.

So, the basic dependency looks like this.

> Flutter updates -> Xcode updates -> macOS updates -> mac device hardware support.

Note: There are other alternatives like [Hackintosh (un-official mac)](https://hackintosh.com/), might be affordable to you, but I don't recommend them as they are prone fail frequently & are not eligible for support from apple.